# Circle over box top right hand corner

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I'm trying to get a circle over the top of a rectangle at the top right hand corner with text in. I just cannot get it to work no matter what I try. Sadly I didn't develop all of this website and it's a bit of a mess here and there and it's becoming very overly complex.

This is an example of what I'm trying to achieve.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tISDz.jpg):

[image]

```css
.home-blue-box {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  border-top-left-radius: 50px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 50px;
}

.home-bg-darkblue {
  background-color: #253250;
  text-align: left;
  padding-bottom: -200px;
}

.student-header {
  font-family: futura-pt, sans-serif;
  font-weight: 300;
  font-style: normal;
  color: #000000;
  font-size: 35px;
  line-height: normal;
}

.home-yellow-button {
  width: 260px;
  height: 50px;
  /*background: linear-gradient(to right, #fddc18 80%, rgb(255 255 255 / 0%) 50%);*/
  background: linear-gradient(to right, #fddc18 80%, rgb(252 220 22 / 50%) 50%);
  background-size: 200% 100%;
  background-position: right bottom;
  transition: all .5s ease-out;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  margin-top: 20px;
}

.home-yellow-button:hover {
  background-position: left bottom;
}

.home-circle {
  position: absolute;
  height: 40px;
  width: 40px;
  border-radius: 40px;
  border: 3px solid white;
  right: -20%;
  margin-left: -25px;
  top: -20px;
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<main id="primary" class="site-main">
  <div id="section-slide">
    <div class="home-slider">
      <div class="span_4_of_4 fifty-trans" alt="" style="background: linear-gradient(to left, rgb(255 0 0 / 0%) 50%, rgb(5 42 62 / 50%) 50%); background-repeat: no-repeat; background-size: cover; background-position: center; height: 715px; position: absolute;"></div>
      <?php if ( have_rows('home_slider')): while ( have_rows('home_slider')): the_row(); ?>
      <?php $image = wp_get_attachment_image_src(get_sub_field('slide_image'), 'slider-image'); ?>
      <div class="span_4_of_4 mainhomebg" alt="" style="background: url(<?php echo $image[0]; ?>); background-repeat: no-repeat; background-size: cover; background-position: center; height: 715px; z-index: -1;"></div>
      <div class="container home-slider-content">
        <div class="row group flex">
          <div class="spanfull_2_of_4">
            <div class="heading-padding font-yellow FuturaPTDemi font-extra-large lineheight-double">
              <?php the_field('slide_heading'); ?>
            </div>
            <div class="heading-padding font-white FuturaPTDemi font-extra-large lineheight-double">
              <?php the_field('property_name'); ?>
            </div>
            <a style="text-decoration: none;" href="<?php the_field('property_link'); ?>">
              <div class="yellow-button-long">
                <div class="blue-text OpenSansSemibold">EXPLORE THIS ACCOMMODATION</div>
              </div>
            </a>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="home-circle"></div>
        <div class="home-blue-box span_2_of_5 flex-center flex-wrap home-bg-darkblue padding-three">
          <h1>Some text
            <h1>

              <a style="text-decoration: none;" href="#">
                <div class="home-yellow-button" style="margin: 20px auto 0;">
                  <div class="black-text OpenSansSemibold">Get Started</div>
                </div>
              </a>

        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Set `position: relative` on the container then set `position: absolute` on the circle and offset it from the top and right with negative values.

```css
.container {
  position: relative;
  width: 200px;
  height: 140px;
  border-radius: 50px 0;
  background-color: blue;
  margin-top: 20px;
}
.circle {
  position: absolute;
  top: -15px;
  right: -15px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="circle"></div>
</div>
```